# Need help updating

Tags: 14.04

I currently have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and want to get Ubuntu 15.04. However, when I go to download it, it doesn't install to my laptop and I can only access the files associated with is. Does anyone know how to get the latest version onto my laptop?

Comment: What's "when I go to download it"? Why do you need to go somewhere to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get do-release-upgrade
```

That will upgrade to the latest version.  If you set up a cron script to run this every 6 months, you will be kept up to date with every new version.

Comment: Just make sure you have regular backups going in case of any oops!

Comment: ^ Absolutely!  You should be doing that anyways.  If you have dropbox you can set it up so that you back up to dropbox.

Comment: How would that get the OP from 14.04 to 15.04? It would try upgrading to 14.10, and likely end up with errors, as 14.10 is no longer supported.

Comment: Well once it upgrades to 14.10 (if it doesn't go to the latest release) then the OP can just run again.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](http://goo.gl/eBZBSd)

You will see that 14.04 LTS will have some extended support that 15.04 will not have.

Do not run after the latest versions (Ubuntu 14.04 i now very stable).

The risk moving to 15.04 is to face problems until all bugs ate solved (I really now what In saying : Windows vista vs Windows XP... Windows 8/8.1 vs Windows 7...)

My advice would be stay on the 14.04 LTS you have (supported above 2018)

laurent06000